# Trouble with Assigning Jobs to Child Processes in C

Tags: c, fork

I am working on a C program that reduces a PGM image. My algorithm should split the job into four unique tasks that my child processes handle, but they each are performing the same task as the child that went before them.

To be more specific, my program should write in four columns of the reduced image to form a completed image, but all I ever get is the first column and only the first column. I have confirmed that each child copies the job of the child before it by skipping the first child. When I do this, only the second column is shown in the result.

Below is a section of my source code:

```
 int cc = cols/selection;  
 int rr = rows/selection;
 unsigned char image2[rr][cc];  //creates the space for output image


 char temp[rr][cc];

 /*
 /* Main part of program
 /* reduces image by selecting every nth pixel and adding it to
 /* image2.
 */

 tp = 5;  /* type==5 */



for (int x = 0; x < numChildren; x++){
 if((childpids[x] = fork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpids[x] == 0)
        {
                /* Child process closes input*/
                close(fd[0]);
                /* Send 2D int array through output*/

                     for (i=0; i< rr; i++)
                       for(j = (cc / numChildren) * x; j < (cc / numChildren) * (x+1); j++)
                       {
                           temp[i][j]=imagePtr[((i*selection)*cols + (j*selection))];
                       }

                write(fd[1], &temp, sizeof(temp));
                exit(x);
        }
        else
        {
                /* Parent process closes output*/
                close(fd[1]);

                /* Read in a 2D int array from input*/
                nbytes = read(fd[0], temp, sizeof(temp));
                 for (i=0; i< rr; i++)
                       for(j = 0; j < cc; j++)
                       {
                           image2[i][j]=temp[i][j];
                       }
        }
}

 imagePtr2=(image_ptr) image2;

 printf("\n Now writing to image file ... \n");

 //creates output image
 write_pnm(imagePtr2, argv[2], rr, cc, tp);
```

Please note that some functions used are part of a library that was given to me for the purpose of writing this program.

Comment: It's suspicious that you do not check the return values from `read` and `write`.  They are not guaranteed to read/write the full number of bytes you requested, and if they don't, your code will never know.

Comment: It would also be really good to see how `fd` is created and how `temp` is declared (the `sizeof(temp)` is suspicious too).  In short it would be good to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).